# For Loop Not Executing Properly wrapped around Try/Except

Tags: python, for-loop, yaml

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def get_users(yaml_file="AD_Users.yml"):
with open(yaml_file, 'r') as stream:
    try:
        data = yaml.load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
return data.itervalues()

 def create_user_in_ad(new_users): #username, password, base_dn, fname, lname, domain):
    # LDAP connection
    for new_user in new_users:
        try:
            logging.info('Connecting to LDAP Server %s ' % LDAP_SERVER)
            ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, 0)
            ldap_connection = ldap.initialize(LDAP_SERVER)
            ldap_connection.simple_bind_s(BIND_DN, BIND_PASS)
            print "Connected to LDAP Server!"
        except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
            print "Error connecting to LDAP server: %s" % error_message
            #logging.info('Unable to connect to LDAP Server %s ' % LDAP_SERVER)
            return False
#           sys.exit(1)

      # Check and see if user exists
        try:
            print new_user['username'] 
            logging.info('Querying AD for user: %s ' % new_user['username'])
            user_results = ldap_connection.search_s(BASE_DN, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                                  '(&(sAMAccountName=' +
                                                  new_user['username'] +
                                                  ')(objectClass=person))',
                                                  ['distinguishedName'])
            print user_results
        except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
            print "Error finding username: %s" % error_message
            logging.info('Unable to query for user: %s ' % new_user['username'])
            return False

      # Check the results
        if len(user_results) != 0:
            print "User", new_user['username'], "already exists in AD:"
            return False
            sys.exit(1)

      # Lets build our user: Disabled to start (514)
        USER_DN = 'cn=' + new_user['fname'] + ' ' + new_user['lname'] + ',' + BASE_DN
        GROUP_DN = 'ou=' + new_user['group_dn'] + ',' + BASE_DN
        user_attrs = {}
        user_attrs['objectClass'] = \
                    ['top', 'person', 'organizationalPerson', 'user']
        user_attrs['cn'] = new_user['fname'] + ' ' + new_user['lname']
        user_attrs['userPrincipalName'] = new_user['username'] + '@' + new_user['domain']

      # Add the new user account
        try:
            ldap_connection.add_s(USER_DN, user_ldif)
            logging.info('Adding user into AD: %s ' % new_user['username'])
        except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
            print "Error adding new user: %s" % error_message
            return False

      # Add the password
        try:
            ldap_connection.modify_s(USER_DN, add_pass)
            logging.info('Password added for user: %s ' % new_user['username'])
        except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
            print "Error setting password: %s" % error_message
            return False

      # Change the account back to enabled
        try:
            ldap_connection.modify_s(USER_DN, mod_acct)
            logging.info('Enabling AD Account for user: %s ' % new_user['username'])
        except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
            print "Error enabling user: %s" % error_message
            return False

      # Add user to their primary group
        try:
            ldap_connection.modify_s(GROUP_DN, add_member)
            logging.info('Adding user to group %s: ' % new_user['group_dn'])
        except ldap.LDAPError, error_message:
            print "Error adding user to group: %s" % error_message
        return
new_users = get_users()
if args.createusers is not "None": 
    create_user_in_ad(new_users)
```

It calls in a YAML File with user info:

```
 User1:
    username: adtest2
    fname: adtest2
    lname: adtest2
    domain: test.com
    group_dn: test
#   group: 

  # User2:
  #    username: testing
  #    fname: testing
  #    lname: bbbbb
  #    domain: test.com
  #    group_dn: test
# #   group:

    ldap_connection.unbind_s()

    print "User %s has been created in AD!" % new_user['username']

    # All is good
    return True
```

The problem right now is its only executing on the second user when it is not commented out, and I'm wondering did I do something wrong in my for loop? It is doing everything I would like for it to do properly. I'm using Python 2.7.13 btw!

Output now shows only the second user:

```
    Connected to LDAP Server!
adtest2
```

Comment: What output do you get that suggests it only executes on the second user? If you add `print new_user`.

Comment: I'm printing the results of the query, in which you can see that I'm printing the username of new_user. I also added a print new_user['username'] to print the user username to the code, still only returning the second person

Comment: Updated the question with output

Comment: How is all that code related to the YAML file? The reading of that happens before it (presumably) since you are only passing in what appears to be a list of dictionaries to the function. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Excellent question, added the function that does it as well as the exeution to the question

Comment: "It calls in a YAML File"? What you present after that sentence is not valid YAML, so you are not reading in what you think you are reading in if you don't get an error message on `load()`.(which you should not use in the first place). Your python code has a return statement outside a function, which is invalid Python, and the second. It is no wonder your code is not working.

Comment: The YAML file just copied over incorrectly, and yes it's reading in properly, its verified that for the first user. I've also changed the file multiple times and reran and it takes in all the new options.

Comment: I figured out the issue. With all due respect many of the issues were not in the code they were simply in the copy over. Please refrain from insults in the future when helping people in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the return was being executed inside of the for loop. I simply moved it outside of the for loop.